# How to change Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker default view?

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using **Bootstrap 3 Datepicker** [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

I want to change the default view of date picker to YEAR instead of DAYS, since I will use it for birth date selection.

I want to have like this as default.

How can I achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`viewMode`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#viewmode) option setting the `'year'` value. There is a [sample](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#view-mode) on the official site and you can see the following code as example:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'years',
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    defaultDate: moment('01/01/1990', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    showClear: true
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

You can use `defaultDate` to set a default date to the picker, so it shows the year that you prefer when it opens.

Comment: Hi @VincezoC, thank you it works, is there option for setting the default year? I want to start from 1990's. Thank you!

Comment: @aldrien.h I've edited my answer setting default year

Comment: Hi, i tried but doesn't work on me. Still showing the year starts from 2011

Comment: Sorry, but I need to know more code to understand you issue. Which `format` are you using? Which value are you setting to `defaultDate`? Anyway, this is becoming a different question :)

Comment: I just have the same code as you, but I will mark you answer since you helped me to my first question. Thank you again :)